# Specify Font Size of Gridview in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm printing gridview in pdf. The gridview is fine. But the cells are not filling in properly. I think if I can decrease the font a bit, the cell will be filled in properly. I've decreased the width. But the cells are being distorted.

Code of Gridview -

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'layout'=>"{items}",
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'hsncode',
            [
                'label' => 'Productname',
                'attribute' =>'productname',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:20%'],
                //'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
                //'format'=>['decimal',2]
            ],
            'batchno',
            //'expdate',
            [
                'attribute'=>'expdate',
                'format'=>['DateTime','php:m-y'],
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:6%'],
            ],
            'mrp',
            'rate',

            'qty',
            'free',           
            'discount',
            [
                'label' => 'Value',
                'attribute' =>'value',
                //'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
                'format'=>['decimal',2]
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'GST%',
                'attribute' =>'gstpercent',
                //'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:6%'],
                //'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
                'format'=>['decimal',0]
            ],


            [
                'label' => 'Total',
                'attribute' =>'totalamount',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:9%'],
                //'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
                'format'=>['decimal',2]
            ],
        ],
        ]); ?>
```

Gridview looks like -
[image]

Please let me know how to specify the font in gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use options for the grid container

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'layout'=>"{items}",
        'options' => ['style' => 'font-size:12px;']
        'columns' => [
```

or directly in column

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'layout'=>"{items}",
        'options' => ['style' => 'font-size:12px;']
        'columns' => [
             [
              'label' => 'your_label',
              'attribute' =>'your_attribute',
              'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'font-size:12px;']
            ]
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks a lot.